# Copy and paste nonblank cells from sheet1 to sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste nonblank cells from sheet1 to sheet2.

I'm getting application/object error.

```vb
Public Sub CopyRows()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    For x = 4 To FinalRow
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 1).Value
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        If Not IsEmpty(ThisValue) Then
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 6).Copy
            Sheets(2).Select
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets(1).Select
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: In general, you want to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code. It's also better to specify which sheet a given range is in (ex.: `Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value` instead of `Cells(x, 1).Value`)

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < 4 Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sr As Long
    
    ' Loop and copy.
    For sr = 4 To slRow
        Set sCell = sws.Cells(sr, "A")
        If Not IsEmpty(sCell) Then
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
            sCell.Resize(, 6).Copy dCell
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Rows copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your original code.  As cybernetic.nomad already pointed out, avoid using Select whenever possible.  You also set your `NextRow` variable to always be the last row in the worksheet instead of the next available row in your destination sheet.  Additionally, because of your use of .Select, you have ambiguous `Cells` calls.

Here is an alternate method using AutoFilter because, for this task, you can take advantage of filtering to only get populated cells without having to perform a loop:

```
Sub CopyRows()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook:     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet: Set wsDst = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim rData As Range:     Set rData = wsSrc.Range("A3", wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If rData.Rows.Count < 2 Then Exit Sub  'No data
    
    With rData
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        .Offset(1).Resize(, 6).Copy wsDst.Cells(wsDst.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    
End Sub
```